# How to parse (French) full month into datetime object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have a string of a date which I want to parse into a datetime object. I have this:

```
$invoice = '9 février 2017'
[datetime]::parseexact($invoice, 'dd MMMM yyyy', $null)
```

But it doesn't work. How can I convert the month (which is always French BTW) into the date time object?

Comment: not sure if its related but $null in ps != null in c#

Answer (score 11):

The 3rd argument to [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the `IFormatProvider`, to which you can pass a [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instance in whose context the string should be interpreted, so you must pass it the object representing French culture:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact($invoice, 'd MMMM yyyy', [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR'))
```

Note that I've had to change `dd` to `d`, since your input string's day index only has a single digit.

---

By passing `$null` as the 3rd argument, you're implicitly using the *current* culture, as reflected in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

<sup>[1] The automatic `$PSCulture` variable works too, but only if the culture wasn't changed in-session.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
$invoice = "Dimanche 21 Janvier 2024"
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact($invoice, 'dddd dd MMMM yyyy', [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR'))
```

Using the format **'dddd dd MMMM yyyy'**, the date will be parsed correctly