# How to parse datetime by ::parseexact in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'v got a problem when trying to parse, and convert string to [DateTime] format in PowerShell using `::parseexact`. Can someone tell me where's my bad?
Here's my code.

```
[datetime]::parseexact('2018-05-07T15:19:17.839+03:00','o', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz')
```

And here's an error

> Cannot find an overload for "parseexact" and the argument count: "3".
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + [datetime]::parseexact('2018-05-07T15:19:17.839+03:00','o', 'yyyy-MM- ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: `[datetime]::parseexact('2018-05-07T15:19:17.839+03:00', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz',$null)`

Answer (score 10):

As mentioned in the comment, you can change your code to `[datetime]::parseexact('2018-05-07T15:19:17.839+03:00', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz',$null)` and that will work for you if you are not concerned with the [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

But as I can see in your code, that you are providing 3 arguments to your `ParseExact` function, which makes me wonder if you are really trying to change the `CultureInfo`. If you want to change your that, you can do something like this -

```
([datetime]::ParseExact($date,"dd/MM/yyyy",[Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-GB'))
```

**OR**

```
([datetime]::ParseExact($date,"dd/MM/yyyy",[Globalization.CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('de-DE'))
```

and so on depending upon your requirement.

**Extra Info -**

As per [the msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx),

> The
>   DateTime.ParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)
>   method parses the string representation of a date that matches any one
>   of the patterns assigned to the formats parameter. If the string s
>   does not match any one of these patterns with any of the variations
>   defined by the styles parameter, the method throws a FormatException.
>   Aside from comparing s to multiple formatting patterns, rather than to
>   a single formatting pattern, this overload behaves identically to the
>   DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)
>   method.

The `style` parameter, is a bitwise combination of enumeration values that indicates the permitted format of s(input date). A typical value to specify is [None](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx).

See the [Get-Date Formatting Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654045/get-date-formatting-culture) for more info.

Comment: The given fully specified formats (from OP and yours) don't require the Globalization.CultutreInfo. This comes into play when parsing foreign language short/long day/month names like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496825/how-to-parse-french-full-month-into-datetime-object-in-powershell)